# Kubernetes pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (eks)

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have following `StorageClass` defined for `aws eks` cluster (3 nodes)

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: aws-gp2
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  zones: us-west-2a, us-west-2b, us-west-2c, us-west-2d
  fsType: ext4
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
```

and have `eks` nodes running in `us-west-2a, us-west-2b, us-west-2c` zones.

When I am trying to deploy `mysql` with dynamic persistent volume

```
---

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: mysql
    env: prod
spec:
  storageClassName: aws-gp2
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi

---

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: mysql
    env: prod
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secret
              key: root-password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

But pod doesn't move beyond `Pending` status.

Pod's event log says :

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age               From               Message
  ----     ------            ----              ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  8s (x7 over 20s)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 3 times)
  Warning  FailedScheduling  8s (x2 over 8s)   default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.
```

I am not understanding why pod is not able to mount the PVC.

I added 1 more node to the eks cluster, so all 4 nodes can span across 4 az's and then re deployed the `mysql` and it worked. Still don't know what was the real issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I know this has been already discussed million times and Im answering 2 years after your question. Most probably you already forgot this question, but community remember everything.

Community answer for next generations...

Everything has been already discussed in similar stack question [Kubernetes Pod Warning: 1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946393/kubernetes-pod-warning-1-nodes-had-volume-node-affinity-conflict)

[Answer from @Sownak Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55514852/9929015): Full, without my modifications. They simply dont need there..

The error "volume node affinity conflict" happens when the persistent volume claims that the pod is using are scheduled on different zones, rather than on one zone, and so the actual pod was not able to be scheduled because it cannot connect to the volume from another zone. To check this, you can see the details of all the Persistent Volumes.
To check that, first get your PVCs:

```
$ kubectl get pvc -n <namespace>
```

Then get the details of the Persistent Volumes (not Volume claims)

```
$  kubectl get pv
```

Find the PVs, that correspond to your PVCs and describe them

```
$  kubectl describe pv <pv1> <pv2>
```

You can check the Source.VolumeID for each of the PV, most likely they will be different availability zone, and so your pod gives the affinity error.
To fix this, create a storageclass for a single zone and use that storageclass in your PVC.

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: region1storageclass
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  encrypted: "true" # if encryption required
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - eu-west-2b # this is the availability zone, will depend on your cloud provider
    # multi-az can be added, but that defeats the purpose in our scenario
```